# Referencing a class packaged in an ear from a JBoss module

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

I'm deploying an ear (myear.ear) application to WildFly 9.0.2. The ear contains an **ear module**, let's call it myjar.jar.

Also, I have an external custom **JBoss module**. From within that module I need (never mind the reason) to call a class packaged within myjar.jar.

Is it even possible???

This is how the **JBoss module** `module.xml` looks like:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="path.to.module.dir">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="..."/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="deployment.myear.ear.myjar.jar"  />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

In case I can address the jar packaged in the ear from that custom module, how should I specify the module name. The above gives the following error:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: deployment.myear.ear.myjar.jar:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException.toError(ModuleLoadException.java:74)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:560)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

Comment: no this is not possible, dependencies can only go the other way deployment --> static module.

Answer (score 0):

The way to include an external jar within a module and load it's classes via the module class loader is referencing it as an external resource (assuming it exists in the specified location is:

```
<sub-deployment name="myjar.jar">
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="../../../modules/path/to/resource/jar" />
    </resources>
</sub-deployment>
```

The pass is relative (here somewhere under the modules directory).

Whereas, dependency between deployments (and sub-deployments) is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible. Ears can only depend on modules, not vice versa